# Android Toolbar Crash Issue - Not all devices

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I'm running into an odd problem. I've got an app running on a bunch of devices, but on one it fails with something seemingly simple that I can't figure out.

The Toolbar works fine on all of my devices - but is causing this error:

> Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/header_color"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Bridge">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="android:background">@color/header_color</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp">
    </activity>
```

MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Logcat Error:

> 2021-02-14 14:04:37.574 13026-13026/com.edtest.devicetools E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.edtest.devicetools, PID: 13026
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.edtest.devicetools/com.edtest.devicetools.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3762)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3938)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2277)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8425)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:572)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:159)
> at com.edtest.devicetools.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8183)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8167)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3938) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2277) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8425) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
> 2021-02-14 14:04:37.600 13026-13026/com.edtest.devicetools I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13026 SIG: 9

The app crashes on the setSupportActionBar EVERY time on certain devices, but not on others.  All devices are running Android 10, so there's no OS difference.

I've read all of the articles about the toolbar
I've tried various combinations of the parent theme with and without the action bar
I can leave or remove the theme windowactionbar and windownotitle statements and seem to have the same result no matter what.

any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Toolbar did you import? Make sure to import the androidx artifact.

Comment: in Main Activity I have import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
is there another one I should have in there?

Comment: No, that is the correct one. If possible share logcat.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I added the logcat above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - I figured out what was happening.  So frustrating I missed this - and it's so crazy to figure some of this stuff out.

Themes are confusing to me for some reason - but that's for me to go figure out later.

Here's what went wrong:

New Android Studio projects have themes.xml
AND also include another themes.xml (night)

I had added all of my app bar styles into the themes.xml - but I had NOT done anything to the (night) version of this file.

And the devices I was experiencing errors on were set to Dark mode in Android settings.

So the app was trying to use the alternate themes.xml and failing.

So either kill off that file if you're not ready for any dual-personality in your app
or embrace it and support Dark mode

Either way - this was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your theme you provide

```
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

change it with

```
   <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

maybe its help!

Comment: Yup - I had tried that - the challenge wasnt this or some combination of how the title bar was coming into the app - it ended up being the fact that there was a 2nd theme for night / dark mode and I had not added all of the right parts to that file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue while trying to run the application on a physical device.

On an emulator it works well because the light theme was selected on an emulator, but on a physical device, it was the dark theme.

Changing it to a light theme on the physical device made the application run properly.

My theme.xml is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

I set the toolbar in Activity as `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: Yup - same thing - I did not realize - or wasnt paying enough attention - that the latest Android Studio automatically adds the night theme into a new blank project.  And the logcat doesnt really point out anything about the night / dark mode vs light mode